# Dynamic product list GTM tag removes null products

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

GTM FB PIXEL purchase data being returned with blank items.
Currently, I have a "hard-coded" variable that expects for an item to be in said index. It works great when the cart is full but I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically determine if the value of said variable is null.

So I also want to do this all on Google tag manager, it can easily be done in javascript but I am using a generic model function for my datalayer. trying to keep my codebase lean.

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue}},
    currency: 'USD',
    content_type: 'product',
    content_ids: ['{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.0.id}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.1.id}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.2.id}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.3.id}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.4.id}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.5.id}}'],
    products:['{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.0.name}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.1.name}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.2.name}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.3.name}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.4.name}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.5.name}}'],
    price:['{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.0.price}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.1.price}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.2.price}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.3.price}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.4.price}}','{{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products.5.price}}',] 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your tag

```
function() {
  var products = {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products}};
  return products.map(function(prod) { return prod.id; });
}
```